# SSIM function in TensorFlow 2.x

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, ssim

I'm trying to use tf.image.ssim() as my loss function for training my model and I explored a liitle bit how people have implemented it. Here they are:

1. [Working with SSIM loss function in tensorflow for RGB images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52798540/working-with-ssim-loss-function-in-tensorflow-for-rgb-images)
2. [Use SSIM loss function with Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357146/use-ssim-loss-function-with-keras)

I have couple questions:

1. In both these threads, the dynamic range suggested for `tf.image.ssim` is 2 when the inputs are normalized between -1 and 1. But I have ran a small sanity check to see if it works or not. Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
from skimage.util import random_noise
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

im = Image.open('E:\\DATA\\train_image_(124).png')
im_arr = np.asarray(im) # convert PIL Image to ndarray

noise_img = random_noise(im_arr, mode='gaussian', var=0.0005) # random_noise() method will convert image in [0, 255] to [0, 1.0]
noise_img = (255*noise_img).astype(np.uint8)

img = Image.fromarray(noise_img)

#normalizing between 0 and 1 and reshaping for SSIM calculation
x = np.reshape((np.asarray(im)/255), [256, 256, 1])
y = np.reshape((np.asarray(img)/255), [256, 256, 1])

#normalizing between -1 and 1 and reshaping for SSIM calculation
x_a = np.reshape((2*(np.asarray(im)/255) - 1), [256, 256, 1])
y_a = np.reshape((2*(np.asarray(img)/255) - 1), [256, 256, 1])

print('No norm: ', str(tf.image.ssim(np.reshape(im_arr, [256, 256, 1]), np.reshape(noise_img, [256, 256, 1]), 255).numpy()))
print('Norm_01: ', str(tf.image.ssim(x, y, 1).numpy()))
print('Norm_11: ', str(tf.image.ssim(x_a, y_a, 2).numpy()))
```

To my understanding, all 3 print statement should give the same value of SSIM, but they don't. When the range is 0 to 1 and 0 to 255, the SSIM result is same, but with the range of - 1 to 1, it is different. To double check, I have calculated the SSIM in MATLAB too, and that nearly agrees with the first two cases. So, is there any other way to compute SSIM/use SSIM as a loss function in TF2? I did the same experiment with `compare_ssim` from skimage, but that one seems to have same result. Am I missing something?

2. Also, when I am using `tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(target, gen_output))` as my loss function, everything is okay. But when I am using `tf.reduce_mean(tf.image.ssim(x, y, dynamic_range)` as the loss function, I'm getting NaN values. Both the threads mentioned above uses either tensorflow 1.x or `model.fit` on tensorflow2.x for training while I am using `tf.GradientTape()` to calculate the gradient and update the weights. Is it possible that the GradientTape function is responsible for returning the NaN values? If so, why and what could be a possible solution?